# PgAdmin Create Server ERRO - Instance '<server at ...> is not persisted

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am having a big problem, I need to create a server in PgAdmin and I never used it before.

I tried to create and this message is showing, I tried to google it but there is no link for the solution.

There is an image to show the message:

Can someone help me, I have a deadline and I am very worried about.

[image]

I tried to create a server and it didn't work.

Comment: Workaround: Use a different tool, pgAdmin is just one of many PostgreSQL clients.

Comment: can you give me a suggestion Frank?

Comment: I like DataGrip, but there is so much more, check this list: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: And of course you use psql, that's the tool everybody has to use one day anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below process, my problem resolved after deleted folder and then reinstalled it

deleted the pgadmin folder within the C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Roaming folder, deleted the pgadmin folder in C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Local and C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL

It's also work for me. Thank you so much

Comment: He is just copy-pasted the correct answer